# On the VMware. Unable to paste exe from a virtual machine to another virtual machine

Tags: copy-paste, vmware

Unable to paste exe from a virtual machine to another virtual machine.
I have installed vmware tool on both computers.
[image]

help me.

---

The error tips: "The file type cannot be determined. You may not have permission to perform this operation."

Comment: What makes you think this should work? Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: As a workaround, share a folder between host and guest1, copy.the file from guest1, and then share a folder between host and guest2, copy the file from host to guest2.